# Need help in configuring XRDP on SUSE Linux ESS 12 SP3

Tags: suse

All these test activity I am carrying out on my AWS instance for my test purposes.

I am bit of new Linux playground and I needed your guys expertise for configuring it. I am trying to install & configuring SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3 (HVM), SSD Volume Type on AWS & stuck up while enable XRDP. So need your help. Actually I am trying to configure XRDP on the AWS instance.

I followed this tutorial but no success : https://www.suse.com/documentation/s...igure_rdp.html'

Previously : All these options were pretty simple & straight forward on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4 (HVM), SSD Volume Type.

Current Issue : Getting the logging screen & then after entering the credentails everything goes blank, I can do anything on the screen. No UI nothing, Even I tried setting the display to 16-bit or 24-bit only but no success.

So let me know your thoughts or suggest some document which explains how to configure Linux 12 for XRDP.

Thanks

Rahul Jain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been solved !!!

Below are the steps I performed & it will be helpful for them who stumble upon the same issue.

```
# zypper update ( to update SUSE Linux Ent. Server)
# zypper install -t pattern gnome-basic
# zypper install xrdp
```

**Enable VNC Remote Login**

```
# Open yast, Select "Network Services", Select first entry "Remote Administration with VNC"
# Enable service
```

Configure Window Manager to use Gnome
Edit file /etc/sysconfig/windowmanager
Change entry DEFAULT_WM="" to DEFAULT_WM="gnome

**Startup the RDP service and make it start automatically after Reboot**

```
# service xrdp start
# chkconfig --set xrdp on
# systemctl start xrdp
# systemctl enable xrdp
```

Above are the steps which I performed to get the activate & use RDP session through my windows, If in-case anybody have any question let me know I will be happy to assist you.

Regards,

Rahul Jain

Comment: StackOverflow is only for questions about programming, not system configuration or administration. It's good that you have an answer, but it doesn't belong on this site in the Stack Exchange network. Consider our sister site [unix.se].